# Dictionary - object reference not set an instance of an object

Tags: object, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception, unityscript

I make in Unity2D and i have a problem.I have an **object** (it has ObstacleMove script) that I want use several times in scene and every instance of this object i want save in Dictionary (Dictionary is in other script and other object). I use in ObstaceleScript:

`player.GetComponent<PlayerMove>().obstacleDictionary.Add(posString, gameObject);`,

everything works, but when i use more than one **object** with ObstacleMove script, console write error: *object reference not set an instance of an object*

So what I can use instead of gameobject in Add(posString, ___); ?

P.S.: *PlayerMove* is script with Dictionary and *player* is object which use this script.

P.S. 2: `Dictionary<string, GameObject> obstacleDictionary;`

*PlayerMove*:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{

Vector3 pos;
public float speed;
public static bool inside;
public Dictionary<string, GameObject> obstacleDictionary;

GameObject gob;

void Start()
{
    obstacleDictionary = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();
    pos = transform.position;

}

void Update()
{
    gob = GetObjectAt(transform.position);
    if (gob == null) inside = false;
    else inside = true;
    print(inside);


    #region Control
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        GameObject go = GetObjectAt(transform.position - new Vector3(speed, 0, 0));
        if (go == null || go.GetComponent<ObstacleMove>().openSide == "right")
        {
            if (inside && gob.GetComponent<ObstacleMove>().openSide == "left") inside = false;
            /*if(inside && gob.CompareTag("BigRed") && go.CompareTag("BigRed")) { }
            else */pos.x -= speed;
        }
    }

    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        GameObject go = GetObjectAt(transform.position + new Vector3(speed, 0, 0));
        if (go == null || go.GetComponent<ObstacleMove>().openSide == "left")
        {
            if (inside && gob.GetComponent<ObstacleMove>().openSide == "right") inside = false;
            pos.x += speed;
        }
    }

    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        GameObject go = GetObjectAt(transform.position - new Vector3(0, speed, 0));
        if (go == null || go.GetComponent<ObstacleMove>().openSide == "up")
        {
            if (inside && gob.GetComponent<ObstacleMove>().openSide == "down") inside = false;
            pos.y -= speed;
        }
    }

    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        GameObject go = GetObjectAt(transform.position + new Vector3(0, speed, 0));
        if (go == null || go.GetComponent<ObstacleMove>().openSide == "down")
        {
            if (inside && gob.GetComponent<ObstacleMove>().openSide == "up") inside = false;
            pos.y += speed;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    transform.position = pos;

    if (inside && gob.transform.position != transform.position)
    {
        print("change");
        ChangeObstacleDictionary(gob.transform.position, transform.position);
        gob.transform.position = transform.position;

    }
}

public GameObject GetObjectAt(Vector3 position)
{
    string pos = position.x + "_" + position.y;
    if (obstacleDictionary.ContainsKey(pos) == true)
    {
        print(obstacleDictionary[pos]);
        return obstacleDictionary[pos];
    }

    else return null;
}

public void ChangeObstacleDictionary(Vector3 lastPosition, Vector3 newPos)
{

    string lastPosString = lastPosition.x + "_" + lastPosition.y;
    string newPosString = newPos.x + "_" + newPos.y;

    //print("test" + lastPosString + " " + newPosString);
    if (lastPosString != newPosString)
    {
        obstacleDictionary.Remove(lastPosString);
        obstacleDictionary.Add(newPosString, gob);
    }
}

}
```

*ObstacleMove:*

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ObstacleMove : MonoBehaviour {

Vector3 pos;
public string openSide;
GameObject player;
string posString;

void Start ()
{
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    pos = transform.position;
    posString = pos.x + "_" + pos.y;


    player.GetComponent<PlayerMove>().obstacleDictionary.Add(posString, gameObject); //warning

    //print(player.GetComponent<PlayerMove>().obstacleDictionary.ContainsKey("3_0"));
}


void Update ()
{


}
}
```

Comment: Answer for deleted answer: But no it's only one of all object in Dictionary, it doesn't throw bugs, but it doesn't work what i want :)

Comment: I realized I misread your question lol

Comment: But thanks, can you help me? :)

Comment: What language is this `script` written in? Is that C#?

Comment: yes, i use c# language

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: this: player.GetComponent<PlayerMove>().obstacleDictionary.Add(posString, gameObject);

**gameObject** is wrong

Comment: Can you help me? :)

Comment: Is `obstacleDictionary` public?

Comment: @GunnarB. Yes, it is public. It works good, when only one object with obstaclescript is in scene.

Comment: So what I need instead of gameobject in Add(posString, ___); ?

Comment: Using the object the script is attached to by saying `gameObject` should in general work for this. I can't really tell, but I don't think the error is originating at this point. I rather think something else in that line is null like `player`. That error is only raised when you try to access something and it is null at that point. `.Add(posString, gameObject)` is not accessing those two so passing them, even if one was to be null, would not cause that error.

Comment: @GunnarB. I restarted Unity and bug was fix, but when i restarted again, bug is back

Comment: Did you make sure that all the objects have a valid reference to the player?

Comment: @GunnarB. They have, 

`GameObject player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");`

Comment: And you checked in the inspector that they actually have that set on runtime?

Comment: Otherwise I would suggest to split that line into multiple for testing and check at which point the error is actually raised.

Comment: There is my simply project: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsCxyl5DQ6LHnXc0ml37TbYf24bt

Comment: It is really weidr, sometimes works, sometimes not

Comment: I think the fault is not in the code.

Comment: I testing it, but i can't find bug :(

Comment: Can you help me? :)